# What does the "test.begin()" function mean in CasperJS?

Tags: testing, methods, parameters, casperjs

I don't quite understand the function `test.begin(String description, Number planned, Function suite)`. What is the parameter `Number planed` for?

Answer (score 17):

`Number planned` is the number of `asserts` that you expect to test. This is totally `optional` and can be thought about as a a sanity check that your test script has actually completed fully.

The [docs states](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html#tester-begin):-

> The planned argument is especially useful in case a given test script
>   is abruptly interrupted leaving you with no obvious way to know it and
>   an erroneously successful status.

An example:-

```
casper.test.begin('when testing foo', 3, function() {
    test.assertEquals(1 === 1, '1 equals 1');
    test.assertEquals(5 === 5, '5 equals 5');
    test.done();
});
```

This test would actually fail as I have defined `3 planned asserts` but only 2 have succeeded (as there are only 2 asserts).